# Loop print after function ends retrieve multiple data

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I've create a web app to store the quotation requested from clients.

A quotation can be multiple so when I print one quotation it's possible I've to print the connected quotation.

To do that I'm trying to print after a function have done to retrieve the data from a json and build the page.

It's possible to have multiple data, so when i click the print button the function have to read the json data for have all the connected quotation, build the page and print it, and do this for any quotation

This function reads the quotation data from server

```
                        function prev_edit(id){
                            return $.ajax({
                                type        : 'POST',
                                url         : 'json/get.php?t=2&p='+id,
                                dataType    : 'json',
                                encode      : true
                            })
                            .then(function(data) {
                                var prom;
                                if ((data)["success"]===false) {
                                    ...do something...
                                    prom=$("#edit").show("slow").promise();
                                }
                                return prom;
                            });
                        };
```

This function works when I click the print button

```
                        $('#prev_print').on("click",(function( event ) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type        : 'POST',
                                url         : 'json/get.php?multi='+$("#id").val(),
                                dataType    : 'json',
                                encode      : true
                            }).then(function(data) {
                                if ((data)["success"]===true) {
                                    $.each((data)["multi"], function( i, n ) {
                                        prev_edit(n).then(function(){
                                            window.print();
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }));
```

I tryied also the deferred object but it seems **prev_edit(n).then** doesn't wait when the function ends the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- rather than using a simple `.each()`, serializing the iteration of `data.multi`.
- Awaiting `$("#edit").show('slow').promise()` by returning it.

You sould also:

- catch & swallow errors arising from the `prev_edit()` process
- catch any unexpected error with a terminal `.catch()`

You should end up with something like this:

```
function prev_edit(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'json/get.php?t=2&p=' + id,
        'dataType': 'json',
        'encode': true
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            ...do something...
            return $("#edit").show('slow').promise();
         // ^^^^^^
        }
        throw new Error('prev_edit failed');
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
};

$('#prev_print').on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'json/get.php?multi=' + $('#id').val(),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'encode': true
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // serialize the preview/print process with data.multi.reduce(...)
            data.multi.reduce(function(promise, n) {
                return promise.then(function() {
                    return prev_edit(n)
                    .then(function() {
                        window.print();
                    })
                    // catch possible error arising from prev_edit().
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        // swallow (don't rethrow) the error.
                    });
                });
            }, Promise.resolve());
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        // no need to rethrow the error as this is top-level code.
    });
});
```

You may need to add some delay into the serialized preview/print process, in order to give yourself time to see the preview. Alternatively you could provide a button which needs to be clicked in order to move to the next preview/print. Either would be quite simple.

Comment: it seems the problem is in $("#edit").show('slow').promise() it not waiting when the show animation is finished to go ahead, but when it begins. I've removed the catching errors for simplify the code

Comment: `return $("#edit").show('slow').promise()` will only cause the process to wait until the #edit element is fully shown (700ms IIRC). If you want it to wait longer, then you'll need to introduce some extra delay, which jQuery makes very simple.

Comment: eg, `return $("#edit").show('slow').delay(1000).promise()`.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: prev_edit(...).then(...).catch is not a function it gives me this error

Comment: Should be OK with jQuery 3+. If not, then replace `.catch(errorHandler)` with `.then(null, errorHandler)`.